# Is initializing the arrayList or map in a constructor good practice?

Tags: java

Is initializing list or map collection in the constructor is advisable in order to avoid null pointer exception when accessing that ArrayList

```
public class ItemsDetail{
    private List<String> items;

    public ItemsDetail() {
        this.items = new ArrayList<>();
    }

}
```

Comment: It's not bad. Consider declaring directly `private List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();` so that you don't need to in all constructors.

Comment: The example you provided is not problematic at all. The problems arise when you want to populate that collection from an source such as a database. That is some time-consuming work that you don't want to have in a constructor.

Comment: I prefer to do so as it helps to avoid NPE from time to time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with this approach.

Of course, instead of initializing the `List` in the constructor, you can initialize it when you declare the instance variable:

```
private List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
```

The only situation in which it would make sense not to initialize the `List` instance variable in the constructor is if you are going to create a large number of instances of your `ItemsDetail` class, and for most of them you'll never access the `items` variable.

In such a scenario, creating multiple `ArrayList`s which you'll never use is redundant. It can be optimized by checking if the `ArrayList` is initialized before accessing it, and only initializing it when necessary (lazy initialization).

Of course, there's no need to do such optimizations unless you find that your program is too slow, and that this optimization helps to improve its performance.

Some JDK classes use this lazy initialization approach. For example, when you write `new ArrayList<>()`, the array backing the `List` is not yet allocated. Instead, an empty array is assigned to the instance variable:

```
public ArrayList() {
    this.elementData = DEFAULTCAPACITY_EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA;
}
```

This saves the creation of a new array (in case you'll never add elements to your `ArrayList`), and also avoid the danger of `NullPointerException` (and the need for `null` checks) by assigning a pre-defined empty array instance to the `elementData` variable.

Come to think of it, this JDK optimization reduces the motivation for you to use a similar optimization in your custom class, since it makes the instantiation of a new `ArrayList` a less expansive operation.